# Erlang: Output Problem

Tags: erlang, erlangweb

In my erlang web application, there is a list, which contains integers to be printed on the web page.
But when the script executes, it prints this, instead of actual list,

Please look at this [Image showing characters for unicode codepoint 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, whitespace, codepoint 15](http://img524.imageshack.us/img524/3442/erl.jpg)

How to format this to gain what I want?
Target list is [1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 15]

Comment: Imageshack is blocked in China. You should think about using decentralized services, why not your own FTP ? Remember the Skype bug a few days ago...

Comment: @Tangui: If http://imgur.com ain't blocked in China, one may use it right from within SO interface (button *Image* or keyboard shortcut Ctrl+G).

Comment: try with [1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21] ;) sorry;) couldnt resist.

Comment: @ Tangui, I'm sorry mate. Next time I'll do that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should do this:

```
P = [1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 15],
Show_on_page = io_lib:format("~p",[P]),
Show_on_page.
```

This will represent any Erlang term on the web page the way you want to see it.

Comment: Actually, you could remove the "Show_on_page =" and the last line to get the same result.

Comment: i just wanted to be more elaborate so that @indranama doesnot get lost here. But thanks for that suggestion

Answer (score 2):

You Web presentation probably like the values more converted to string (lists).

```
1> [ integer_to_list(I) || I <- [1,1,2,3,5,8,13,15] ].
["1","1","2","3","5","8","13","15"]
```

Maybe join them as well depending on your formatting.

```
2> string:join([ integer_to_list(I) || I <- [1,1,2,3,5,8,13,15] ],",").
"1,1,2,3,5,8,13,15"
```