# Send erlang binary to browser

Tags: html, erlang

I would like to send erlang terms (erlang-based back end) to the web browser.  It is easy enough to encode a term on the erlang side using something like:

```
term_to_binary(Term)
```

or:

```
binary_to_list(term_to_binary(Term))
```

The problem of course is that scrambled garbage shows up on the browser end.

Question:  Is there either some encoding I can use on the browser end, or more likely, some Content-Type I can accept on the browser end to unscramble this?

Thanks.

Comment: out of curiosity, could you give us the reason why you would do this?

Answer (score 2):

Use `io_lib:format("~p",[Term])`. It will produce a string representation of the erlang term which can be showed on a web page. Consider also checking out this **[question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4595361/431620)** and its **[answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4595816/431620)**.

Answer (score 2):

There is [piqi](http://piqi.org/) that provides extensive mapping mechanisms between .piqi (its record definition language), json, xml and protobuf. It's a really cool tool, that we use all the time to map between all of these formats. 
Typically when I build something (in Erlang) that needs to provide some sort of data to something else, I start with a piqi definition file that defines the structure. The piqic compiler generates Erlang record definitions and conversion code to do conversions easily.

Highly recommended, but it might be overkill for what you're doing.

Answer (score 1):

Encode it with [base64](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64). Get it via ajax, then decode either with native `window.atob` or any of numerous available libs.

Comment: I won't touch ajax.  I just run standard html, cgi, etc.  Any other suggestions?

Comment: Hardly base64 encode can help to read erlang terms in browser.

Comment: @blinkov question was about _sending_, and base64 is an "ok" transport encoding for the web.

Answer (score 1):

If it is for a web browser, I would go for a Json string, it's unicode and browsers support it nativaly.

Maybe consider Json and do something like this for strings:

```
1> HelloJerome = "Hello Jérôme".
"Hello Jérôme"
2> HelloJeromeBin = list_to_binary(HelloJerome).
<<"Hello Jérôme">>
3> HelloJeromeJson = << <<"{\"helloJerome\":\"">>/bits, HelloJeromeBin/bits, $\", $} >>.
<<"{\"helloJerome\":\"Hello Jérôme\"}">>
```

In the browser console:

```
jerome = JSON.parse('{\"hello\":\"Hello Jérôme\"}')
```

Now

```
jerome.hello == "Hello Jérôme"
```

There are some good lib out there [ejson](https://github.com/davisp/ejson) or [mochijson2](http://code.google.com/p/mochiweb/source/browse/trunk/src/mochijson2.erl) are the classic ones but ktuo or ...